# how to find documents except ones updated two hours ago?

Tags: javascript, datetime, mongoose

Somehow my head isn't working around at the end of the day.

I am trying to query documents except ones that has been updated within the last two hours.

Found this to get time two hours ago

```
    const TWO_HOURS = 2*60*60*1000, // milliseconds
        now = new Date(),
        twoHoursAgoDate = new Date(now.getTime() - TWO_HOURS);
```

then I did this for my query

```
const query = await Model.find({
            updatedAt: { '$lt': twoHoursAgoDate, '$gt': now }
        });
```

I tried playing around with the `$lt` and with or without the `now`.
None seems to be working.

Someone able to give me a hand with this?

Thanks in advance for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part where you subtract the two hours is causing problems as it converts it to milliseconds. Try this:

```
now = new Date();
now.setHours(now.getHours() - 2);
```

And then in your query use this:

```
const query = await Model.find({
    updatedAt: { '$lt': now }
});
```